# Can't handle Floating Point Exception (FPE) for the second time

Tags: c, unix, ubuntu, posix

I have written a program that handles signal for Floating point exception and I am using Ubuntu 10.4.

Here's my source code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <setjmp.h>

sigjmp_buf mark;

void GeneralHandler(int signo)
{
    switch(signo)
    {

        case SIGFPE:
            printf("\nERROR : Invalid Arithmetic operation.\n");
            siglongjmp(mark, signo);
            break;
    }

    exit(signo);
}

int main(void)
{
    int i = 0,value = 0, ans = 0;
    struct sigaction act;
    act.sa_handler = GeneralHandler;

    sigaction(SIGFPE, &act, NULL);

    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        if(sigsetjmp(mark, 1)) continue;
        printf("Value : ");
        scanf("%d" ,&value);
        ans = 5 / value;
        printf("%d / %d = %d\n", 5, value, ans);
    }

}
```

I am using siglongjmp and sigsetjmp methods for jumping from the handler method to the main method inside for loop.

It works fine for the first time and displays **ERROR : Invalid Arithmetic operation.** and then displays **Floating point exception** for second time and then exits.

Program output :

> searock@searock-desktop:~/C$ ./signal_continue
> Value : 0
> ERROR : Invalid Arithmetic operation.
> Value :0
> Floating point exception
>   searock@searock-desktop:~/C$

I am not sure what's wrong in my program? Why doesn't it show **ERROR : Invalid Arithmetic operation.** for the second time? Can someone point me in a right direction?

Comment: You should check the return value from `scanf()` and exit the loop if it does not return 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have not initialized your `struct sigaction`
It's possible `act` contains garbage values, e.g. configuring the signal handler to [SA_RESETHAND](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/sigaction.html) or something other bad.

Do struct

```
sigaction act = {};
```

or

```
memset(&act,0,sizeof act);
```

Comment: Is memset() part of posix or stdlib ?

Comment: @Searock - memset() is basic Standard (ISO) C; header `<string.h>`.

Comment: Thanks for bearing with me. I am new to Posix.

Comment: Empty initializer lists like `{}` are fine in C++, but you have to use `{0}` instead in C, at least according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201101/how-to-initialize-an-array-in-c

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you are supposed to `logjump()` out of a signal handler back into main code. The signal handler is supposed to just handle the signal and then return and let the main program execution go on in it's normal way.

I'm not sure what you *are* supposed to do about a SIGFPE, though. The man page for `signal()` says, not very promising:

> According to POSIX, the behavior of a process  is  undefined  after  it
>          ignores  a  SIGFPE, SIGILL, or SIGSEGV signal that was not generated by
>          kill(2) or raise(3).  Integer division by zero  has  undefined  result.
>          On some architectures it will generate a SIGFPE signal. [...] Ignoring  this
>          signal might lead to an endless loop.

Comment: Please bear with me as I am a beginner. Is it harmful if I continue the program after the signal ?

Comment: @Searock: Generally signals are asynchronous events that are handled separately by the signal handler, the main program is not really directly affected by that. It should (automatically) continue to run as normal if the signal handler didn't kill it in response to the signal. But I'm no expert on this topic and don't know about how you are supposed to react to a FPE. (For division by zero there is of course the problem that the main program would still need to produce some result for that expression if it wants to continue executing.)